# FluentUI - Dashboard template

Tags: fluentui-react

I didn't understand if it is possible to customize a dashboard template of Fluent UI
https://dev-int.teams.microsoft.com/storybook/main/index.html?path=/story/ui-templates-dashboards--default.
for example:
Question 1 - is it possible to increase the height of a single card to ?
Question 2 - is it possible to change the background of a card from white to transparent background?